# Js file load differently in two development computers

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I have this js file that loads correctly in one computer while on the other computer it displays as below with a lot of slashes. I have totally no idea what is going on.

Anyone can help?

```
// define angular module/app
//var angularticsGf = angular.module('angularticsGf', ['angulartics', 'angulartics.abc']);

var marlogApp = angular.module('abc', []);

function waypointController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.shipper_id = '';
    $scope.delivery_control_id = '';

    $scope.load_delivery_controls = function() {

        alert('trigger');
//        if ($scope.populate !=  true) {        
//            $scope.size = null;
//        }
//        $scope.sizes = [];
//        
//        if ($scope.geography != null && $scope.brand != null && $scope.fit != null) {        
//            $http({
//                    method: 'GET',
//                    url: base_url + 'api/sizes',
//                    params: {
//                        geography : $scope.geography,
//                        brand : $scope.brand,
//                        fit : $scope.fit
//
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never thought I'd say this on Stackoverflow but.... clear your cache. Looks like someone was testing something and it's cached on one computer.